# Can i wire a RS485 to a RS232 DB9 serial connector?

Tags: networking

well the title says it all I have a RS485 out put on a device and i need to be able to access the data  from the  RS232/DB9 connector on my pc, what the best way to go a converter or wiring my own?

Comment: can you please take your time and explain exactly what you're looking for, this is so vague. `you need to get at it` means what exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The best way" depends on you, and your resources, so you choose.

Here's the pin-out, and what's needed to convert RS-485 to a (RS-232) COM port:

[image]

[Source](http://pinouts.ru/Converters/rs485_cable_pinout.shtml)

Here's a whole site dedicated to converting one to the other, to help you make your choice:

http://www.rs232-to-rs485.com/